# Populating column based on conditions on other 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I've a situation in which I need to

print "SAME" - where

> either of 2 columns is empty or
>
> both are empty or
>
> repeating the same pattern

print "UP" - if

> COL2 greater than COL1 (only at that point, if it continues the same pattern in following rows then it should only print "SAME" as mentioned above)

print "DOWN" - if

> COL1 greater than COL2 (only at that point, if it continues the same pattern in following rows then it should only print "SAME" as mentioned above)

e.g.

```
DATE         **COL1  COL2    RESULT**
2019-01-01      0             SAME
2019-01-02      1     2       **UP**
2019-01-03      2     3       SAME
2019-01-04      3     4       SAME
2019-01-05      4     1       **DOWN**
2019-01-06      5     2       SAME
2019-01-07      6     3       SAME
2019-01-08      7     7       SAME
2019-01-09      8             SAME
2019-01-10      9     8       SAME
2019-01-11                    SAME
2019-01-12            4       SAME
2019-01-13      7     8       **UP**
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try creating any SQLs?

Comment: you have not mentioned any programming language here ? or you want to process it using MySql only?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Also which column(s) provide the order you expect?

Comment: One approach is to do it in two steps. First identify the pattern for each row and then identify whether the new pattern corresponds with the previous pattern

Comment: @asprin I've not tried anything in SQL because I'm not able to think about it. How to proceed on it ? If it could have been in any coding language then it is just a 2 mins work to write a loop and use flag to generate it but in mySQL I'm not much hands-on.

Comment: @OnkarMusale its MYSQL only.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
version 8.0.16
and there is no order.

Comment: @Strawberry didn't get it.

Comment: If there is no order, then your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of this solution is a little contrived, but perhaps someone can think how to remove the contrivance. Also, because of the slightly hacky way I've done this, as written, this solution is only appropriate for versions prior to 8.0...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(DATE DATE PRIMARY KEY
,COL1 INT NULL
,COL2 INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2019-01-01',0,NULL),
('2019-01-02',1,2),
('2019-01-03',2,3),
('2019-01-04',3,4),
('2019-01-05',4,1),
('2019-01-06',5,2),
('2019-01-07',6,3),
('2019-01-08',7,7),
('2019-01-09',8,NULL),
('2019-01-10',9,8),
('2019-01-11',NULL,NULL),
('2019-01-12',NULL,4),
('2019-01-13',7,8);  

SELECT date, x result FROM
     ( SELECT date
     , CASE WHEN @p = result THEN @i:= 'same' ELSE @i:=result END x
     , @p:= result
  FROM 
     ( SELECT date
            , @prev := CASE WHEN col1 > col2 THEN 'down' WHEN col1 < col2 THEN 'up' ELSE @prev END result
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @prev:='same') vars -- this is the contrived part
        ORDER
           BY date
     ) n
     , (SELECT @p:=null,@i:=null) more_vars 
 ORDER
    BY date
    ) b
 ORDER BY date;
  +------------+--------+
  | date       | result |
  +------------+--------+
  | 2019-01-01 | same   |
  | 2019-01-02 | up     |
  | 2019-01-03 | same   |
  | 2019-01-04 | same   |
  | 2019-01-05 | down   |
  | 2019-01-06 | same   |
  | 2019-01-07 | same   |
  | 2019-01-08 | same   |
  | 2019-01-09 | same   |
  | 2019-01-10 | same   |
  | 2019-01-11 | same   |
  | 2019-01-12 | same   |
  | 2019-01-13 | up     |
  +------------+--------+
```

Comment: These are all null/ empty.

Comment: I've update my question with an extra column date which is a primary key and decides the order.

Comment: Highly appreciable @Strawberry.
Need one more favor, kindly help me to understand the SELECT query.

Comment: can you please help explaining this select query step by step ?